Cropping a raster using terra does not return the expected extent
I have a raster whose extent is -180.049996946546, 179.949996948242, -90.05, 90.05 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
I need it to align it with other rasters that have the same CRS but an extent of -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
I am trying to cut it using the crop function of the terra package but for some reasons this does not return the exact extent I want, namely -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).
Can anyone offer any advice?
myraster |> ext()
SpatExtent : -180.049996946546, 179.949996948242, -90.05, 90.05 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
new_extent
SpatExtent : -180, 180, -90, 90 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
myraster_cropped=crop(myraster,new_extent ,extend=TRUE)
myraster_cropped |> ext()
SpatExtent : -180.049996946546, 180.049996946546, -89.95, 90.05 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

Details of myraster
> myraster
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 1801, 3600, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : -180.05, 179.95, -90.05, 90.05  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source(s)   : memory
varname     : t2m (2 metre temperature) 
name        :    t2m_1 
min value   : 229.8191 
max value   : 306.1671 
unit        :        K 
time        : 2000-01-01 UTC


Does setting crop(... , extend = FALSE) help (see documentation: ?crop) ?

No it does not .. I am using extend= TRUE just because the max coord of my raster is slightly lower than the one of the template

Run myraster and add the result as an edit to your question. Also, is the extent and resolution identical in all of your other SpatRaster objects? Add this information to your question as well. This will help to determine to most appropriate solution.

Your data
libary (terra)
r <- rast(xmin=-180.05, xmax=179.95, ymin=-90.05, ymax=90.05, res=.1)

This is, of course, a very odd extent. Especially having latitudes >90 and < -90 makes no sense. Unfortunately, climate model data if often provided that way.
If you do
newext <- ext(-180, 180, -90, 90)
crop(r, newext) |> ext()
#SpatExtent : -180.05, 179.95, -89.95, 89.95 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

The extent does not change the way you would like because crop can only remove entire rows and columns. You can use terra::resample
x <- rast(res=0.1)
x <- resample(r, x)

And, yes this will change the values (depending on the value for argument "method") but that is desirable in this case since the extent shifts half a cell, there is no good way around that.

Hi @Robert Hijmans thanks for commenting. I initially tried to resample using a raster template but this will inevitably alter the values - slightly- but it will change it as it uses an interpolation for continuous raster .. I was wondering whether I could avoid it

alternative approaches may depend on the rater geometry you are providing. You could edit your question and show that.

I edited my question @Robert Hijmans
